# how to declare a database driven dictionary in django which is globally accessable in templates and not views.py dependent

Tags: python, django

I need to declare a database driven dictionary globally accessable in all templates and which should not be view dependent as I need it globally for all templates.

I tired to write a context processor

But while adding the context processor in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'myapp.context_processors.myfunction",
)
```

It keeps loading multiple times. Then going through that issue I learn that as context processors loads via RequestContext , so as i am calling RequestContext  multiple times it keeps loading.

So is there a way i would define it once and can access globally in templates , also which does not hamper my site performance

`myfunction` will be like :

```
from ipc.declarations.models import MainDeclaration
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def myfunction(request):
    declarationId = 2991
    declaration = get_object_or_404(MainDeclaration, pk=declarationId,  user=request.user.id)
    return {'sectionGlobal': declaration}
```

Comment: Please paste the code for "myfunction", I suspect that you could use caching

Comment: Why are you calling RequestContext multiple times per request?

Comment: Except the view also i have `annotations.py` where i have to call the `RequestContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context processors are kind of overused... and you now know why. Better to use them only for very very simple, lightweight stuff (link injecting settings etc).

The right way to allow templates to access data not provided by views is to write your own template tags - in this case a simple assignment tag should be enough :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags

Comment: Yes initially I thought so then switch to context processors. Now your suggestion I  accepted and tried it worked perfectly :)